# UTL_FILE not creating a file and not giving an error

Tags: oracle-ebs, utl-file

I am running a concurrent program which runs a package.procedure, it is suppose to take output of a cursor and add it into a .csv file. Earlier it was running fine however when I am running now the file is not getting created in the server directory, instead it is dumping the o/p in the output file even though no code which dumps the file data in output file.

The directory exists and there are permissions to read, write and execute for this.

The log or o/p file does not give any error and we have exceptions defined.
I am using r12.1.3 and linux 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the directory is defined in the [UTL_FILE_DIR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams226.htm#REFRN10230) initialization param in order to write a file out to the file system using UTL_FILE.  Don't forget to bounce the DB after adding the directory.

Answer (score 0):

issue found. The reason was I was running the wrong concurrent program. Silly of me. Ran the correct program and now getting the o/p.

Thank you all for your help and comments.

Thanks